# How to handle multi-inheritance in Swift?

Tags: swift

This is probably 2 swift questions in one...

How do I solve a situation where I want to extend an existing base class (`UIView` in my case) with functionality that requires stored properties? ...so that I can reuse the code for other classes?

I have tried to solve it through composition below, but I don't know if there is a more obvious way that I just can't see as I am fairly new to swift...

The second question:
In my implementation I have an abstract class `ManagedComponentImpl` which  needs an eventReceiver object which is going to be the containing `UIView` subclass.

The problem I have with my implementation is that swift forces me to define an object binding `where Receiver:NSObject` for `ManagedComponentImpl`, so that I can declare the optional variable `eventReceiver` as weak. (and I guess I would create a memory leak otherwise). However I would want to use this implementation on a variety of objects (which could of course all inherit `NSObject`, but they do not actually need to for other reasons but this, so it seems odd). So question number 2: Is there a way to avoid this?

EDIT: And yes! I made a mistake mixing model and view code here, but I guess the fundamental problem remains when you switch UIViewController for UIView :-)

```
public protocol ManagedConnection {
    var connectionKey:String { get set }
}


public protocol ManagedComponent: ConnectionObserver {
    var connectionKey:String { get set }

    func connectTo()
    func disconnectFrom()
}

public protocol EventReceiver: ConnectionObserver {
    var variableSet:Set<VariableID>? { get }
    var handleVariableUpdates: ((Set<VariableID>)->Void)? { get }
}

class ManagedComponentImpl<Receiver: EventReceiver> where Receiver:NSObject {

    public var _connectionKey: String = Shared

    //The connection Key
    public var connectionKey: String
    {
        set {
            disconnectFrom()
            self._connectionKey = newValue
            connectTo()
        }
        get {
            return _connectionKey
        }
    }

    // The  varset needed by this control
    weak var eventReceiver:Receiver!

    //  handler for the status pane variables
    //
    var connectionObserverHandlerID:UInt16 = 0
    var eventHandlerID:UInt16 = 0

    public init(receiver:Receiver) {
        self.eventReceiver = receiver
    }


    public func connectTo() {
        guard let manager = Connections.shared[self.connectionKey] else { return }
        let connection = manager.connection

        // disconnect any previous connections
        disconnectFrom()

        // Connect the connection observer
        connectionObserverHandlerID = connection.addConnectionObserver(observer: eventReceiver)

        if let variableSet = eventReceiver.variableSet, let handler = eventReceiver.handleVariableUpdates {
            eventHandlerID = connection.requestVariables(variables: variableSet, handler: handler)
        }
    }

    public func disconnectFrom(){
        guard let manager = Connections.shared[self.connectionKey] else { return }
        let connection = manager.connection

        // Disconnect
        if connectionObserverHandlerID != 0 {
            connection.removeConnectionObserver(id: connectionObserverHandlerID)
        }

        if eventHandlerID != 0 {
            connection.unRequestVariables(ident: eventHandlerID)
        }

    }

}


class ManagedUIView: UIView, ManagedComponent, EventReceiver {


    private var component:ManagedComponentImpl<ManagedUIView>!

    public var variableSet:Set<VariableID>? 
    public var handleVariableUpdates:((Set<VariableID>)->Void)?

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        component = ManagedComponentImpl<ManagedUIView>(receiver: self)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        component = ManagedComponentImpl<ManagedUIView>(receiver: self)
    }

    var connectionKey:String {
        set {
            component.connectionKey = newValue
        }
        get {
            return component.connectionKey
        }
    }

    func connectTo() {
        component.connectTo()
    }

    func disconnectFrom() {
        component.disconnectFrom()
    }

    func notifyState(state: ConnectionState) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - for everybody reading this, the answers are:
- The problem should probably be solved by a delegate and not by inheritance.
- To avoid inheriting from NSObject: the problem seems to be that protocols can not only be implemented by classes. Therefore the protocol needs a class limitation to work as weak references. As a result ManagedComponentImpl does not need to be generic any more and I can just have a weak CAPEvent receiver optional.